# URL-decode a string in Common Lisp

Tags: url, common-lisp, drakma

I have a string that contains an escaped URL:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Ffoo%3Dbar+baz
```

I'm trying to decode it to the following:

```
http://example.com?foo=bar+baz
```

However, I can't find any suitable function exported by Drakma.  I can *en*code like so:

```
* url-string

"http://example.com?foo=bar+baz"
* (drakma:url-encode url-string :utf-8)

"http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Ffoo%3Dbar%2Bbaz"
```

... so I figure I'm on the right track.  If anyone could supply a nudge in the right direction I'd appreciate it :-)  I'm using SBCL 1.0.54, built from source on 64-bit Linux Mint 13.

If it helps clarify what I'm trying to do, in Ruby, I'd do the following:

```
> uri_string = "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Ffoo%3Dbar+baz"
 => "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Ffoo%3Dbar+baz" 
> URI.decode uri_string
 => "http://example.com?foo=bar+baz"
```

Comment: In case you're wondering, I know it's decidedly weird that the _entire_ URL is escaped, including the protocol specification.  I'm trying to write a cross-platform download client for an Australian online music store that provides files containing lists of entirely-escaped URLs like the example above.

Comment: just asking the obvious: (apropos "DECODE") does not show any interesting function? (apropos "DECODE" "DRAKMA") ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A quick SLIME session.

```
CL-USER> (ql-dist:system-apropos "url")

#<SYSTEM curly / curly-20120407-git / quicklisp 2012-05-20>
#<SYSTEM curly.test / curly-20120407-git / quicklisp 2012-05-20>
#<SYSTEM do-urlencode / do-urlencode-20120407-git / quicklisp 2012-05-20>
#<SYSTEM url-rewrite / url-rewrite-0.1.1 / quicklisp 2012-05-20>

CL-USER> (ql:quickload :do-urlencode)
```

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-d</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>`do-urlencode`<kbd>RET</kbd>

```
DO-URLENCODE:URLDECODE
  Function: (not documented)
DO-URLENCODE:URLENCODE
  Function: (not documented)
DO-URLENCODE:URLENCODE-MALFORMED-STRING
  Type: (not documented)
DO-URLENCODE:URLENCODE-MALFORMED-STRING-STRING
  Generic Function: (not documented)

CL-USER> (do-urlencode:urldecode "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Ffoo%3Dbar%2Bbaz")

"http://example.com?foo=bar+baz"
```

Comment: Thanks :-)  I'm still learning the 'Lisp way' of doing things ... it never even crossed my mind that there might be a way of getting help on Quicklisp packages from the REPL.

Answer (score 5):

Found another solution, with [Quri](https://github.com/fukamachi/quri), a uri handling library with encoding and decoding utilities (for uri and parameters):

```
(url-decode "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Ffoo%3Dbar%2Bbaz")
;; "http://example.com?foo=bar+baz"
```

To install with `(ql:quickload :quri)` and then optionaly `(use-package :quri)`.

(my sources: [lisp-lang.org's recommend libraries](http://lisp-lang.org/wiki/article/recommended-libraries) and [awesone-cl](https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl)).